# Do VPS hosts typically offer an option to take snapshots of the virtual machine (VM)?

Tags: vps

Is taking a snapshot of the virtual machine that a VPS runs on a standard feature provided by [VPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_server) hosts?

Comment: It's not a standard feature, but there are VPS hosts that offer snapshots. You can search for them using a combination of something like "VPS hosting with snapshots".

Comment: It depends on the company. I am now hosted on Negative0 who offer me weekly snapshots. I was earlier hosted on some other company that did not.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it depends on what you mean with *snapshot*. Do you mean an image of the OS, or a *backup*?

Some VPS providers offer images and/or backups, and some don't. It's not 'usual'. I have used one VPS host, they gave me a free backup server of 50 GB. I was considering switching to another provider, they didn't offer backups but they did offer snapshots (images).

I also want to note that most VPS providers offer backups instead of images.

*To answer your question*: no, not typically. At many VPS providers, backup space is an add-on, but it will cost you more. Some VPS providers do the same for images.

Comment: Thanks for upvote, I now have enough reputation to comment :)

Answer (score 0):

The term *snapshot* can mean many things to many people. If you mean a backup, they should be doing that already and you should be able to do this yourself too. If you mean image backup then that would have be to asked of the ISP as to whether they perform image backups or not. Image backups usually mean having access to a server with a bootable floppie or cd-rom but there may be other options out there that I am not aware of. VPS would not normally afford this option except perhaps at the ISP level.

It has been a long time since I performed an image backup. I used to use Ghost since it was the best at the time. There are free image backups out there as well as regular backups that you should be able to use including free backup software available depending upon the linux install you have.

Comment: The term "snapshot" comes from virtual machine/server software (like that of VMWare), and means to take a picture/image of the current state of the virtual machine so it can be rolled back to that state at a later time if needed.

Comment: Thanks Dan. Similar options exist within Windows. I got it. I have been out of the hosting world for quite a while though I worked with various VM(s) back in my consulting days. We used to use the term snapshot for image style of backups. My mistake.

Comment: @dan That's what I meant, a VM Snapshot.